# decimal point mysql 5.7.14 with wampp server not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

decimal point mysql 5.7.14 with wampp server not working.

this is try to set decimal point

[image: setdecimaloint]

after saving this table structure show 
[image: grams_of_gold not set]

it will need to show like this

[image]

someone help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following instead of phpmyadmin

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableNameHere MODIFY COLUMN YourColumnNameHere decimal(4,2)
```

Comment: try but show error
Out of range value for column 'grams_of_gold' at row 124

Comment: it is working when use decimal (10,4) , i think my exiting data cause error.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this via sql

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN grams_of_gold decimal(10,4);
```

The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments are as follows:

M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65.

D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Answer (score 0):

sometime it is not working in wamp but it will work xampp or old mysql server but we can use this alter query . i have faced same problem and solved it

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY COLUMN colum_name decimal(10,4);
```

hope it will solve your problem